# Can I rewrite this do-while loop as a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, foreach, do-while

Is there a way to write this code more elegantly with a foreach loop? The "create a new entry" logic is thwarting me, because it needs to execute even if pendingEntries contains no items.

```
ItemDto itemToAdd; // an input parameter to the method
IEnumerator<Item> pendingEntries = existingPendingItems.GetEnumerator();
pendingEntries.MoveNext();
do // foreach entry
{
  Item entry = pendingEntries.Current;
  if (entry != null) // fold the itemToAdd into the existing entry
  {
    entry.Quantity += itemToAdd.Quantity; // amongst other things
  }
  else // create a new entry
  {
    entry = Mapper.Map<ItemDto, Item>(itemToAdd);
  }
  Save(entry);
} while (pendingEntries.MoveNext());
```

Comment: So you can have non-existing (null) entries in a list named "existingPendingItems"? Strange naming...

Comment: What does `Save(entry)` do? Does it add to `existingPendingItems` or to some other list? If `existingPendingItems` can be changed during iteration, a foreach should not be used.

Comment: @Sjoerd I think the purpose of the null-check is only to handle the case where the enumerator has no items.

Comment: @Sjoerd, the poor naming is an artifact of renaming items for posting the code snippet. Save() persists the item in a database and does not effect existingPendingItems.

Comment: @Jay, you are correct. The null check is intended to handle the situation where the collection is empty.

Comment: @neontapir Then why are you using the rather rare do-while() instead of the usual `while()` loop? You shouldn't access Current when it is not valid - see answers below.

Comment: @Sjoerd, agreed, hence the desire to re-write it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (Item entry in existingPendingItems.DefaultIfEmpty())
{
    Item entryToSave;

    if (entry != null) // fold the itemToAdd into the existing entry
    {
        entry.Quantity += itemToAdd.Quantity; // amongst other things

        entryToSave = entry;
    }
    else // create a new entry
    {
        entryToSave = Mapper.Map<ItemDto, Item>(itemToAdd);
    }

    Save(entryToSave);
}
```

The key is the [Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179.aspx) call — this will return a sequence with a `default (Item)` item if the sequence is empty. This will be `null` for a reference type.

Edit: fixed bug mentioned by neotapir.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but it involves writing to the loop variable, which the compiler won't allow.

Comment: @neotapir: my in-brain compiler is obviously not as comprehensive as the C# compiler. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

This should be rewritten. I don't know what kind of collection you're using, but `Current` is undefined in your case since `MoveNext` could have returned `false`. As stated in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58e146b7.aspx):

> Current is undefined under any of the following conditions:
>   The last call to MoveNext returned false, which indicates the end of the
>   collection.

Here is how I would rewrite it:

```
bool isEmpty = true;
foreach (Item entry in existingPendingItems)
{
  ProcessEntry(entry, itemToAdd);
  isEmpty = false;
}
if (isEmpty)
{
  ProcessEntry(null, itemToAdd);
}
```

- `ProcessEntry` contains the logic for a single entry, and is easily unit testable.
- The algorithm is cleared to read.
- The enumerable is still only enumerated once.

Comment: Good catch about first `MoveNext()` call. Didn't mentioned this at first. +1.

Comment: That's true, Current is undefined (=null) if there are no items in the collection.

Comment: Undefined doesn't mean `null`. Undefined could be anything, even throwing an exception (that's actually what arrays do, for example).

Comment: @JulienLebosquain, I see you point after reading the [documentation on Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.current.aspx). Looks like it willthrow if MoveNext() returned false.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd suggest something like this:

```
ItemDto itemToAdd; // an input parameter to the method
if (existingPendingItems.Any())
{
    foreach(Item entry in existingPendingItems)
    {
        entry.Quantity += itemToAdd.Quantity    
        Save(entry);
    }
}
else
{
    entry = Mapper.Map<ItemDto, Item>(itemToAdd);
    Save(entry);
}
```

I think this makes the intent of the code much clearer.

EDIT: Changed count to any as per suggestion. Also fixed the add quantity logic

Comment: The problem here is that all the logic that you put in the `foreach` block is going to have to be duplicated in the `else` block, for that one item, which makes the code brittle. Also, because all we know is that `existingPendingItems` is enumerable, you'd have to invoke the `.Count()` extension method to compare to 0; you're better off using `.Any()` in this scenario because it will return true as soon as it can be determined that there is at least one item, rather than counting all items just to see if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rewrite it as more standard `while` method. And you've forgot that `IEnumerator<T>` implements `IDisposable`, so you should dispose it.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( Item entry in pendingEntries.Current)
{
    if( entry != null)
        entry.Quantity += itemToAdd.Quantity;
    else
       entry = Mapper.Map<ItemDto, Item>(itemToAdd);
    Save(entry)
}
```

cant exactly test it without the items

Comment: But if there's nothing in `pendingEntries.Current`, then the `foreach` loop won't execute. The OP wants the loop to execute at least once ("The "create a new entry" logic is thwarting me, because it needs to execute even if pendingEntries contains no items.").

Comment: `pendingEntries.Current` is a single `Item`; can't `foreach` that.

Comment: could encapsulate it with an if else check

Answer (score 0):

```
var pendingEntries = existingPendingItems.Any()
    ? existingPendingItems
    : new List<Item> { Mapper.Map<ItemDto, Item>(itemToAdd) };

foreach (var entry in pendingEntries)
{
    entry.Quantity += itemToAdd.Quantity; // amongst other things
    Save(entry);
}
```

The idea here is that you set yourself up for success before iterating. What are you going to iterate over? Either the existing entries, if there are any, or just a new entry otherwise.

By handling this up front, so you know you've got something with which to work, your loop stays very clean.

Comment: I like where you are going with this, but I believe this implementation would end up doubling the quantity if we create a new pendingEntries collection from the itemToAdd.

Comment: @neontapir Ah, I see -- you don't actually want to do any add'l processing on the new item, just save it; is that right?

Comment: Correct, the Save operation adds a new item to the database. This method prevents duplicate items from being added.